# Sort-Object with Get-Unique in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

My code:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter *

$paths = $users.DistinguishedName

$unique_paths = $paths | Sort-Object -Property DistinguishedName | Get-Unique
```

My Problem is if I execute this it replies only 1 path and not like the expected 200 or so. Why is that? What am I missing?

Comment: `DistinguishedName`s are unique so why are you trying to `Get-Unique` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$paths = $users | Select-Property DistinguishedName
$paths | Sort-Object -Property DistinguishedName | Get-Unique -AsString
```

or just: (taken the comment from [**MathiasR.Jessen**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen))

```
$users.DistinguishedName | Sort-Object | Get-Unique
```

Quoting the [`Get-Unique`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-unique) cmdlet document:

#### [Example 4: Get unique processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-unique#example-4-get-unique-processes)

> The `AsString` parameter tells `Get-Unique` to treat the **ProcessName** values as strings. Without this parameter, `Get-Unique` treats the **ProcessName** values as objects and returns only one instance of the object, that is, the first process name in the list.

[**`-AsString`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-unique#-asstring)

> Indicates that this cmdlet uses the data as a string. Without this parameter, data is treated as an object, so when you submit a collection of objects of the same type to `Get-Unique`, such as a collection of files, it returns just one (the first). You can use this parameter to find the unique values of object properties, such as the file names.

Comment: The values in `$paths` wouldn't have a `DistinguishedName` property...